# Converting .txt files into one .csv. Exported information overwrite the first line. Any Tips?

Tags: java, csv

I have been working on a project to read data off of multiple .txt file to convert it to a .csv file.  My issues is that the exported data keeps overwriting the first line so everytime i export the file it only shows the last line. Does anyone have any tips to help me out?

```
//Reading the information from the files.
for (String fileName : textFileNames) {
  try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(stack + "\\" + fileName));) {
    fileIn = sc.nextLine();

    while (fileIn != null) {
      String line = fileIn;
      String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
      StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");

      for (String strVal : split) {
        joiner.add(strVal);
      }

      line = joiner.toString();
      line = line.startsWith(",") ? line.substring(1) : line;
      System.out.println(line);

      BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv"));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      // Append strings from array
      sb.append(line);
      sb.append("\n");


      br.write(sb.toString());
      br.close(); 

      fileIn = sc.nextLine();
    } 


    sc.close();

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Class_Organizer_Krause.class.getName())
          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }

}
```

Comment: Concatenate in a file with just a newline before you pull in data?

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating the `BufferedWriter` within the while loop, essentially re-creating the file every time you loop to a new line in your input file.

Move the construction of the BufferedWriter out of the while loop (right before it), move the close statement to right after the while loop and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv", true));` should solve your problem.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

By the way you should move these Resources creations inside the `try` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html to avoid having unclosed resources if an exception occurs

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(stack + "\\" + fileName));
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myfile.csv", true);
     BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fw);
) {
 ...
 // you can remove br.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it :)

Comment: @Brandon, please use the checkmark icon next to this answer to indicate it is the answer. This will give the answerer more points and will place a permanent indicator that this is the correct answer.